# The error "This project is incompatible with the current version of visual studio" displayed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I installed Vs 2010 Express in my PC, and created a poject named myproject with .net 4.0, it works well in  Vs 2010 Express.

Now I installed Vs 2012 Express in my PC, and open the project myproject and upgrade it to .net 4.5, it wells well in  Vs 2012 Express too.

I delete the project myproject all files, then restore it from my old backup file, when I try to open the project from  Vs 2010 Express, I get the following  information.
"This project is incompatible with the current version of visual studio", why?

How can I open the project in  Vs 2010 Express?  I guess the  Vs 2012 Express maybe mark the project as .net 4.5 and stored the information in the somewhere of hard drive. Although I restore the project myproject from old backup file,  Vs 2010 Express still think it is a project of .net 4.5.

Thanks!

Comment: When you opened it in VS2012 did the project conversion wizard come up?  If so, this would have changed the project into a VS2012 project.  Also, yes the target framework is stored in the project.

Comment: I have deleted the project all files and restore it from old backup file, when I try to open the project from Vs 2010 Express, I get the following information.
 "This project is incompatible with the current version of visual studio".

Comment: This didn't have to be closed. I'm running into same situation and would like to have seen a solution!

Comment: I was getting the same error, although in a different situation. For me the solution was to edit the .csproj file, changing the TargetFrameworkVersion from "v4.5" to "v4.0". This at least allows the project to be loaded, although it may result in compiler errors if the program is dependent on 4.5 features.

Comment: Hmm, this question had previously been closed, so I posted my possible answer as a comment above. Now the question has been reopened, so I'll repost my answer as an answer.

Answer (score 35):

If the message "This project is incompatible with the current version of Visual Studio" is due to an attempt to open a project targeting .Net 4.5 with Visual Studio 2010, then the "solution" or workaround is to edit the .csproj file and change the TargetFrameworkVersion from "v4.5" to "v4.0". That at least allows the project to be loaded, although it may result in compiler errors if the program is dependent on 4.5 features.

Comment: @JonnyBest This is only a solution if there are no compiler errors after the change...

Comment: @habakuk I agree. Also note that the OP's project was originally targeting net 4.0. So switching back won't introduce any new compiler errors.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a little old, but just in case the above solutions don't work: don't be an idiot like me and try to open an MVC project using "VS for Desktop" instead of "VS for Web" (or vice-versa), since it will give you the incompatible message.

I use TFS at my job and I tried to open a MVC project via the TFS Solution Explorer.  I wasn't paying attention to which Visual Studio version I had open and since both IDE's look alike, I was confused at what was going on - a common mistake, I'm sure =P

Comment: Also don't make the mistake to use the Windows version for building a (Windows) Desktop application. You need the desktop version for that. Microsoft likes to confuse..

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting the same error for a project which is actually an extension (.vsix), please install [Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30668)

Answer (score 3):

Installing [KB2781514 - Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36020) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check the directory that contains the solution file for an `UpgradeLog.htm` file. It will probably show what's wrong. In my case I tried to open an ASP.NET project, but the **Web Developer Tools** were not installed.

The Web Developer Tools can be installed afterwards by going to the Control Panel and to modify your existing Visual Studio installation. After adding Web Developer Tools the project opened without issues.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the **Component Model Cache** (Visual Studio for C++).

in VS2013 it is located in

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache
```

in VS2015 in

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```

Rename this folder and restart visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error because during the BizTalk install I did not check the Developer Tools and SDK checkbox.  I went back and modified my installation and that error went away for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to load a BizTalk Project in VS2012 without BizTalk installed on your developer machine, will result in this error and the projects will load. This should be the first thing you check.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all your extensions are same as in previous version. For me, when I upgraded from old PC to New PC, I didn't downloaded correct extensions hence resulting in above issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced out with this problem, the solution was:

1. Open VS2017
2. Go to **Tools**
3. Go to **Extensions and updates**
4. Search for **Reporting Services Project** and then "Enable"; close your VS.
5. Open again your project/solution.

--
MT