# Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate compatibilty issues with Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, compatibility

Whenever I try to run Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate on Windows 8 Professional x64 bit I receive the following dialog:

This program has compatibility issues:

[image]

Any idea why should there be any compatibility issues for the product which was released for Windows 8?

Comment: Update3 is out, do you need to upgrade your version?

Comment: I shall check it out. I haven't received any Visual Studio related updates through Windows Updates so far.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305 download the webinstaller and then execute it. It doesn't come from Windows Updates. It is directly inside VS IDE -> Tools -> Extensions and Updates. Beware, it is slooooow....

Comment: Thanks @Steve, I'll get back in few hours with a response after I apply the updates.

Comment: I just figured that the update is around 2 GB so that will take some time. Can anyone confirm if it does indeed fixes my problem?

Comment: Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901518/visual-studio-2012-express-is-suddenly-incompatible-with-this-version-of-window an answer says that Update2 fixed the problem.

Comment: @Steve: I just confirmed that after installing the Update 3, the compatibility issue has been resolved.

Comment: Then If you don't mind I will add this as an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a problem already signaled by other users, seems that installing the Update2/Update3 will resolve the problem.

You could trigger the install of the Update going to the menu `Tools`, selecting `Extensions and Updates` and then checking for Updates. Beware, before to start be sure to have plenty of time. It is a long process and is not very fast